# TypeScript string replace with regex, groups and partial string

Tags: regex, typescript, replace

I want to use regex to format a number inside an input as I type it.
My problem is: Since I'm using groups to format the number, it only formats when the string matches the regex.
Here's an example:
The full number is: `12312312312` | Formatted would look like: `123.123.123-12` .

If I type `1231231` for example, it doesn't formats to `123.123.1` as I was expecting, only if I type the entire number.

This is my function:

```
format(value){
    // This function returns the formatted string on user input
    return value.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d+)/, "\$1.\$2.\$3-\$4");
}
```

Is there any way to make the remaining groups optionals?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do it using

```js
function formatStr(str){
  str = str.replace(/(\d{1,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,2})/g, function(a, b, c, d, e){
        let ret = "";
        if(b != "")
            ret = b;
        if(c != "")
            ret = ret+"." + c;
        if(d != "")
            ret = ret+"." + d;
        if(e != "")
            ret = ret+"-" + e;
        return ret;
  })
  console.log(str);
}

formatStr('12312312312');
formatStr('1231231');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `format` function with 2 calls to `.replace`:

1. First we insert a dot after every 3 digits
2. Second we replace 3rd dot with hyphen

**Code:**

```js
function format(value) {
    // This function returns the formatted string on user input
    return value.replace(/(\d{3})/g, '$1.')
                .replace(/((?:\d{3}\.){2}\d{3})\./, '$1-');
}

console.log(format('1231231'));  //=> 123.123.1
console.log(format('12312312312')); //=> 123.123.123-12
```